# How Can I save a file when user deletes it

Tags: c#-4.0

Every One

How Can I save a file when user deletes it.

I mean to say that, in Normal Case When User Delete A file Then that File Goes to Recycle Bin or When User Delete a file Permanently Then it is stored in Hard disk Some Where. I want To Save It In My Own Folder.
Please Help How Can I Do this.

Thanks.....

Comment: Thats why we have recyclebin :)

Comment: We need more info no this what exactly are you trying to achieve in code?

Comment: You want to program a tool to recover deleted files, but you have no understanding about that area whatsoever. I suggest, you first read up on how these tools work.

Comment: Nice Q?  @Shoban: But, when we removed permanently ({shift}+{del}) it won't show in recyclebin right. BUt, using some softwares we can get that files too (like tuneup utility). how the doing it. I hope, they read hard disk sectors!

Comment: Files are NOT actuallay deleted. They are just removed from the mapping table (not sure about the correct term here). So its possible to recover data as long as no WRITE action was performed in those sectors.

Comment: If you are looking to undelete files, there are [many tools](http://www.google.com.au/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=recover+deleted+files) out there that do this for you. If you want to do this yourself, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think right now is to use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) Class and get notified when a file is deleted but this can be used only for individual files/folders but watching an entire OS for deleted files is different.

Edit: Another option is to watch Recycle Bin but not 100% effective. Check this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/netfxbcl/thread/059469f6-429a-40ca-9611-185c045fb6d9) in MSDN forums.

Comment: also FileSystemWatcher is not very good at watching networked drives